# Disabling zoom when double click on polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have some polygons on a map and when the user double clicks on them, I want no zoom to occur. However, I want double click zoom to be enabled on other parts of the map. Is there any way I can implement this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe the dblclick-event of the polygon(s) and call the stop()-method of the event when it occurs:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygonObject,'dblclick',function(e){e.stop();})
```

Comment: here's a link to the docs too - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MouseEvent