# disable double click zoom in google maps while drawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dojo

I want to draw a polyline on the maps.
i am not using the Drawing lib from google maps api..
i have written my own..

problem:
Before starting the line draw i disabled the double click zoom as below

```
map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: false });
```

double click event is added to line end. 
after this event i am enabled by calling the

```
map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: true });
```

but still the zoom is happening.

even if i put the stop event code in double click.

```
 mouseEvent.stop();
```

Comment: `{disableDoubleClickZoom: false}` will **enable** the double-click-zoom

Comment: after changing that the double click zoom is not working... before that both the line stop and zoom was happening.. now only line stop will happen.. but the zoom will not happen..

Comment: I had the same issue and pasted the setting into marker section instead of map section. After that it worked...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278409/disabling-zoom-when-double-click-on-polygon

Answer (score 16):

It should be the other way around:

To disable

```
map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: true });
```

To enable

```
map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: false });
```