# Google maps API - disable double click zoom when click on Polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have single polyline on my map. I add dblclick event to it. It is working but also map is zooming. How to disable zooming when double click on polyline? (Or anything else with dblclick event);

Any event propagation, event stop or something?

I know and I can use `map.setOptions({disableDoubleClickZoom: true });` but it is not what i really want to do.

EDIT: STUPID HACK

In polyline `'dblclick'` event just added at start :  `map.setZoom(map.getZoom-1);`

Comment: post your 'stupid hack' as an answer to your question, it may be of benefit to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way to do this through the api:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygonObject,'dblclick',function(e){e.stop();})
```

[Disabling zoom when double click on polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278409/disabling-zoom-when-double-click-on-polygon)

Answer (score 0):

**STUPID HACK**

In polyline 'dblclick' event just added at start :  map.setZoom(map.getZoom-1);

So first u deacrease zoom and then increase.